# Using Extract Text Plugin with Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, extract-text-plugin

I'm trying to learn how to use Extract Text Plugin and I found this example:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry:  './src',
  output: {
    path: 'build',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: __dirname + '/src',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css")
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
  ]
};
```

Why is the `"css"` used as a loader ? I tried to look at the docs but still can't understand this.

Thank you all in advance for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

The extractTextPlugin can work with sass, less postcss etc so its asking plugin to only look for `css`. thats why you are using css there.

```
extractCSS.extract([ 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader' ])

extractLESS.extract([ 'css-loader', 'less-loader' ])
```

Comment: so the `css` in the example above is just an extension file ? if so, why is it possible cuz the docs say that the function needs a loader.

Comment: what are your original intentions... understanding why 'css' used or want to use  css with css loader?

Comment: it's about understanding why 'css' used